# Postgres full text search on array column, with index

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

Using Postgres, I want to perform a full text search that includes an array column, using an index. Let's start with a hypothetical schema:

```
CREATE TABLE book (title TEXT, tags TEXT[]);
-- tags are lowercase a-z, dashes, and $
```

We want a query that searches title and tags for some text. A straightforward query with reasonable semantics, recommended by many SO answers, is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM book 
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', array_to_string(tags, ' ')) || to_tsvector('simple', title)
      @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'mysearchterm');
```

That works. The dashes and dollar signs in tags effectively no longer exist but that's ok for this application. However, we have millions of records and need an index:

```
CREATE INDEX book_fulltext_idx
    ON book using GIN 
        ((to_tsvector('simple', array_to_string(tags, ' ')) || to_tsvector('simple', title)));
```

Uh oh! This fails because `array_to_string` is not IMMUTABLE. There are SO answers that suggest wrapping array_to_string in an immutable function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_array_to_string(arr ANYARRAY, sep TEXT) 
RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS $$
    SELECT array_to_string(arr, sep);
$$;

CREATE INDEX book_fulltext_idx
    ON book using GIN 
        ((to_tsvector('simple', my_array_to_string(tags, ' ')) || to_tsvector('simple', title)));
```

The index create works! **But it never gets used**. EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the above SELECT always results in a sequential scan. Postgres is apparently too smart for this trickery.

```
Aggregate  (cost=4348818.79..4348818.80 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=107489.124..107489.125 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on book  (cost=0.00..4348543.45 rows=110135 width=0) (actual time=50.689..107477.408 rows=24641 loops=1)
        Filter: ((to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, my_array_to_string(tags, ' '::text)) || to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, title)) @@ '''mysearchterm'''::tsquery)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 5354819
Planning Time: 0.144 ms
Execution Time: 107489.157 ms
```

I'm stumped. Is there some way of improving this?

---

### New strategy: Use `array_to_tsvector`.

```
CREATE INDEX book_fulltext_idx
    ON book using GIN 
        ((array_to_tsvector(tags) || to_tsvector('simple', title)));

SELECT * 
FROM book 
WHERE array_to_tsvector(tags) || to_tsvector('simple', title)
      @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'mysearchterm');
```

This works! The index is used! It's fast!

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on book  (cost=2005.04..76150.11 rows=26973 width=147) (actual time=5.281..425.128 rows=946 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((array_to_tsvector(tags) || to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, title)) @@ '''apple'''::tsquery)"
  Heap Blocks: exact=790
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on book_fulltext_idx  (cost=0.00..1998.30 rows=26973 width=0) (actual time=4.468..4.468 rows=957 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((array_to_tsvector(tags) || to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, title)) @@ '''mysearchterm'''::tsquery)"
Planning Time: 0.113 ms
Execution Time: 425.371 ms
```

**BUT** the semantics of the search are problematic. `array_to_tsvector` interprets the array as raw lexemes. `to_tsquery` strips out $ and dashes. That means tags with dollar signs or dashes are unsearchable.

```
-- This can NEVER match the tag `$mysearchterm`
SELECT * 
FROM book 
WHERE array_to_tsvector(tags) || to_tsvector('simple', title)
      @@ to_tsquery('simple', '$mysearchterm');
```

Is there some way to make this do what I want? Seems like I want something like `array_to_tsvector('simple', tags)` but that function does not exist.

---

### New strategy: Two indexes and OR

```
CREATE INDEX book_tags_fulltext_idx
    ON book using GIN (array_to_tsvector(tags));

CREATE INDEX book_title_fulltext_idx
    ON book using GIN (to_tsvector('simple', title));

SELECT * 
FROM book 
WHERE array_to_tsvector(tags) @@ '$mysearchterm' OR to_tsvector('simple', title)
      @@ to_tsquery('simple', '$mysearchterm');
```

This produces the right answer in a reasonable amount of time, but breaks the semantics of search. You can't search for `titleword tagword`. The WHERE clause requires both words in the tags, or both words in the title. No bueno.

---

### Epilogue

It looks like I either need to figure out how to index the tags array concatenated with the title, or somehow munge the values that are passed to array_to_tsvector. I'm not quite sure how to do either of those things. Any ideas?

We're using PG11, but I can upgrade if it will make a difference.

Comment: Your plan shows an aggregate node, but your query does not use aggregation.  Please show the true plan and true query.

Comment: Your definition of my_array_to_string should restrict itself to text[] input, not anyarray.  That way it is less likely to get misused.  Functions that lie about their immutability should be handled with care.

Comment: You first formulation with my_array_to_string works for me.  It is willing to use the index (for example, with enable_seqscan=off), but might choose not to if it thinks too many rows will match compared to the size of the table.  So with there you have just a planning problem.

Comment: I tried with enable_seqscan=off and couldn't get it to use the index. However, look at my answer - rearranging the query & index seems to have worked. I have no explanation for why.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that got the index working. I can't explain it.

This does NOT work:

```
CREATE INDEX book_fulltext_idx
    ON book using GIN 
        ((to_tsvector('simple', immutable_array_to_string(tags, ' ')) || to_tsvector('simple', title)));

SELECT * 
FROM book 
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', immutable_array_to_string(tags, ' ')) || to_tsvector('simple', title)
      @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'mysearchterm');
```

This however DOES work:

```
CREATE INDEX book_fulltext_idx
    ON book using GIN (to_tsvector('simple', title || ' ' || immutable_array_to_string(tags, ' ')));

SELECT * 
FROM book 
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', title || ' ' || immutable_array_to_string(tags, ' '))
      @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'mysearchterm');
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=81092.50..81092.51 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=129.780..129.781 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on book  (cost=296.49..81025.24 rows=26902 width=0) (actual time=1.990..129.519 rows=1576 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, ((title || ' '::text) || immutable_array_to_string(tags, ' '::text))) @@ '''mysearchterm'''::tsquery)
        Heap Blocks: exact=1302
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on book_fulltext_idx  (cost=0.00..289.76 rows=26902 width=0) (actual time=1.605..1.606 rows=1576 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, ((title || ' '::text) || immutable_array_to_string(tags, ' '::text))) @@ '''mysearchterm'''::tsquery)
Planning Time: 0.509 ms
Execution Time: 129.906 ms
```

I cannot explain why the query planner thinks "take vector of concatenated strings" is different from "concatenate vectors of strings" but there you have it.